# Reading text files in Java and using data

Tags: java

I am required to evaluate the contents of a `.txt` file, the file includes 5 numbers, all spaced apart by one (ex: 5555 55 45 47 85) on one line.

The problem isn't reading the file, but actually using each number in the file.

**Question:** How can I grab the 5 numbers and store each into a unique variable?

Code so far:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;

public class PassFail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {            
        try{
            FileReader file = new FileReader("C:\\new_java\\Final_Project\\src\\student.txt");
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

            String line = reader.readLine();
            reader.close();

            System.out.println(line);

        } catch(Exception e) {System.out.println("Error:"+ e);}
    }       
}
```

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far? Refer [ask]?

Comment: One solution: Read the line as a string, split it on space and parse them `int`s. Feel free to edit your question or ask a new one when you are stuck on either of those steps.

Comment: Just edited. Sorry about that.

Comment: `line.split(" ")` then parse them to `ints` with `Integer.parse(...)`.

Comment: Awesome, to the docs I go. LOL. I am fairly certain I was looking for the split() method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the file line by line, which you already did. Then you can split the string on space character and iterate over the fields and parse them to Integer

```
s= reader.readline()
String tokens[]=  s.split(" ");
int nums[]  = new int[tokens.length];
for(int i=0; i<tokens.lenght; i++) {
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Awesome. This looks just like what my professor did in class. Thank you.